# Single aggregate column / running value sum on chart

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We're currently porting some excel reports to SSRS. One of those reports has a graph where the last column is the MTD (Month to date) average for both series (Availability and Availability Goal) just like the example below:

[image]

I did some research about RunningValue() but whenever I did it it would add a second bar to my graph (the running value would have the same group).

Is it possible to have only one aggregate column (just like the screenshot) ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to force the average through the SQL query. For example, if your resulting table shows days of the month, and the Availability value, you could UNION a "dummy" day (max days of the month + 1) with the averaged value. You can either add an addition column to your SQL for the label names, i.e. the "dummy" day would show "Average", or in SSRS you can change the Label expression to replace the last value with a text.

Comment: Hi Pops, thanks for the answer :) After some tinkering I did just what you said, but before you posted the answer. I'm going to edit the question with it so I can share the knowledge. Cheers!